# Profilers not able to take heap/thread dump

Tags: java, freeze, profiler, heap-dump, thread-dump

I have a Java desktop application which hangs at-times while running a scenario.

I tried to take heap and thread dump for analysis.
Up until the application hangs I am able to take the heap and thread dumps but once the application hangs neither thread dump nor heap dump works.

The profilers just behaves like nothing happened or hanged.

I tried , Jprofiler, JvisualVm, and also Jstack command.

None of these applications can take a dump. When I tried to connect to the application after it’s hanged, profilers cannot attach to it.

What’s the reason behind it ? I assume that the profiler needs a thread in application to be able to attach to it and that is hanged?

Is there any workaround for this .